# vb.net use System.Threading.Thread for call print web browser dost work

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, printing, webbrowser-control

i have problem in my application . i have 2 winform and call function from form 1 to a function in form 2 for print a web browser but dost work. 
here my code :

form 1 :

```
Dim th As System.Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Task_A)
th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
th.Start()

Public Sub Task_A
    Call form2.fishsefaresh()
End Sub
```

form2 :

```
Public Sub fishsefaresh()
Dim fac As String = " HTML CODE "
Dim FILE_NAME As String = "my_app.html"
Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)
objWriter.Write(fac)
objWriter.Close()

Dim we As WebBrowser = Form2.WebBrowser1
we.Navigate("file:///" & IO.Path.GetFullPath(".\my_app.html")

 While we.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
 Application.DoEvents()
 End While

 we.Print()
```

when i run app nothing happend ( i set printer divise and inestall in my computer ) , i thing webbrowser have problem when use System.Threading .

tax

Answer (score 0):

Using `Application.DoEvents()` is not a good idea, and I cannot understand why you would even do it when you already are in a background thread?

What I suggest you do is to remove the loop calling `DoEvents()`, and instead subscribe to the WebBrowser's `DocumentCompleted` event. You can unsubscribe to it afterwards again, which will cause it to be raised only once.

Replace **all this:**

```
Dim we As WebBrowser = Form2.WebBrowser1
we.Navigate("file:///" & IO.Path.GetFullPath(".\my_app.html")

While we.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
Application.DoEvents()
End While

we.Print()
```

With this:

```
Dim we As WebBrowser = Form2.WebBrowser1

AddHandler we.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted

we.Navigate("file:///" & IO.Path.GetFullPath(".\my_app.html")
```

Then declare the event subscription method:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    Dim wb As WebBrowser = DirectCast(sender, WebBrowser) 'Cast the control that raised the event to a WebBrowser.

    wb.Print() 'Print the page.
    RemoveHandler wb.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted 'Remove the event subscription.
End Sub
```

Hope this helps!